# How to convert h:selectOneMenu item to a List<String> with custom JSF converter?

Tags: jsf-2, converters

On the registration page I want the users to be able to select only one role. Therefore I use `<h:selectOneMenu`

```
    <h:selectOneMenu id="roles" value="#{register.user.roles}"  required="true">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="EMPLOYEE" itemLabel="EMPLOYEE" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="MANAGER" itemLabel="MANAGER" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
```

`<h:selectOneMenu` returns `String` object. However, in order to persist it to the database I need to get   `List<String>` . Here is converter I use

```
@FacesConverter(value="aConverter")
public class AConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, String arg2)
            throws ConverterException { 
        List<String> result = null; 
        result.add(arg1.toString()); 
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object arg2)
            throws ConverterException {
        return arg1.toString(); 
    }
```

How should I convert  `<h:selectOneMenu` return `String` to a `List` ? 
I get `NullPointerException`

Comment: 1: use arg2, which is the value, not arg1, which is the select component.
2: `List<String> result = null;` is the cause of null pointer exception. try something like `new ArrayList<String>()` instead of null.

Comment: what do you mean by all combinations? if you initialize a list as null and then add to it on the next line, you will obviously get a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<h:selectOneMenu id="roles" value="#{register.user.roles}"  required="true">` 
here you are storing the value in a string. Instead, in your managedBean create a variable as ArrayList and use that in your JSP page to save the value of selectOneMenu. I think it should work and you don't need converter.